# Translatepress translating base language products perfectly but issue in fr products

Tags: wordpress, plugins, customization

I have an issue when I'm translating products. I'm importing products from amazon some are English language products and some are French products. TranslatePress automatically translate products that are come in English language because English is base language

but when I import products from amazon French version they come in French language TranslatePress not translating those in English language. Can anyone tell me how I can translate those products automatically?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to translate automatically any object (post type) in bulk with TranslatePress or with any related addon. You have to translate manually one-by-one.

If you mean something different, please, edit your Question.

Take care ;)

Comment: Can't we customize or embed any script in the translate press plugin that translates those products, not in the base language(eng) automatically?

Comment: From my experience, no! In this case the whole process needs different approach and it's not about a simple-single code snippet that can fix your problem! But, lets wait if someone else can help you! :)

Comment: And It is translating eng language products in bulk into french automatically